# OSX terminal vs Docker CLI

Tags: macos, docker, terminal

I'm not able to get what is the purpose of Docker CLI (started by Kinematic) - vs regular OSX terminal.

I have `docker` command available in both (OSX terminal and Docker-CLI), but when typing in:

```
//OSX terminal
$ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

// Kinematic terminal
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
mariadb             5.5.47              a31b2e03c00b        6 months ago        238.8 MB
mysql               latest              d617bcfd159e        6 months ago        360.3 MB
mysql               5.7.9               a5ad9eb2ff48        8 months ago        359.9 MB
<none>              <none>              9ee13ca3b908        8 months ago        125.1 MB
```

and the same for the rest of the commands like `docker-compose up`, they work at the terminal started with Kinematics but not on my local terminal.

Can you please explain me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due the virtualization of the Docker environment on MacOS. The docker environment is not available as a native application but contained in a virtual machine. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/):

> Docker for Mac is our newest offering for the Mac. It runs as a native
>   Mac application and uses xhyve to virtualize the Docker Engine
>   environment and Linux kernel-specific features for the Docker daemon.

You do not need to access that machine manually in any way. The Docker Terminal listed under your Applications as well as Kitematic will do that for you.

However, if you take a look at the virtual machines listed in VirtualBox you will find a VM named `default` which is the one created during the Docker installation.

So the docker CLI is kind of a adapter between your local OSX terminal and the terminal of the Docker environment. The CLI somehow pipes the commands from your OSX terminal to the Docker environment.

Comment: `eval $(docker-machine env default)` will setup your OSX terminals environment so the `docker` cli can connect to the Docker Toolbox boot2docker `default` VM.

Comment: In fact Docker Terminal make for you the `eval $(docker-machine env default)`. Exactly it does `bash -c "clear && DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/metzger9/.docker/machine/machines/default DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 /bin/bash"`. You can see it with a CTRL-D which logout the session and then find the last command with the upper arrow. The best solution is to record the result of `docker-machine env default` in your .bachrc. The next time you open a OS X Terminal you will have the `env` variables needed to make docker run (as natively)

Comment: I did an error, it is not bachrc, but bash_profile.